# TextLabel shifts up when detailTextLabel becomes multiline

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, frame, detailtextlabel

i'm currently making an app where the suer selects an `MKMapView` annotation and then the title of the annotation(pin) is set to a `detailtextLabel` in a Right Detail `UITableViewCell`.
My Problem is that when the text is large, the `detailTextLabel` becomes multiple lines. When this happens the `TextLabel` of the cell(the one the left) shifts up. Heres What I've tried:

- In the cellForRowAtIndexPath Method, I tried adjusting the frame through the following code:

  `CGRect frame = cell.textLabel.frame;`

  `frame.origin.y = cell.frame.size.height/2;`

  `cell.textLabel.frame = frame;`

  Where cell is a `UITableViewCell` that is set to right detail
- Subclass the cell and tun try to adjust the frame in the `-(void)layoutSubviews`

How do I stop it from going up and keep it at the center of the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a custom layout of UITableViewCell, then you need to add your custom UI elements to its `-[UITableViewCell contentView]` instead of trying to modify geometry of standard UI elements that are created by default.

So, in your case, you need to add two `UILabel`s and set their position so that:

1. Title label will not move at all
2. Detail text label will be also multiline

In this way you'll be able to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make the font size adjustable amount to the text.
I think you can use,

cell.detailTextLabel.adjustFontSizeToWidth = Yes;
And also set the numberOfLines to 0.

Hope that solves the purpose.